# How to create a new column with added 2:30 hrs to the current timestamp in mysql or using linux shellscript?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table in MySQL database which registers events for a particular user with a timestamp in UTC. I want to create a new column with `2:30hrs` added to the time for all the events recorded. The table has multiple columns.

Ex:-

```
         date                Event              User
 2018-07-19 04:40:27         regis              hunt
 2018-07-19 04:40:27        Extra_one           poliu
 2018-07-19 04:40:27       temperature          Yinri
```

Expected outcome is to add a new column with `2:30:10 hrs:mins:sec` added to the above timestamp in the `date` column.

```
         date                Event           User        newtime
 2018-07-19 04:40:27         regis           hunt      2018-07-19 07:10:37
 2018-07-19 05:41:47       Extra_one         poliu     2018-07-19 08:11:57
 2018-07-19 14:10:37      temperature        Yinri     2018-07-19 16:40:47
```

I'll be downloading it locally  and working too, so solution with linux-scripts/sed/awk is also fine. I tried using `addtime()` but I am not able to make change for all the entry in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function.

```
UPDATE your_table_name 
SET newtime = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL '2:30:10' HOUR_SECOND);
```

**OR**

MySQL also allows operator `+` to add datetime interval, in lieu of using `Date_Add()` function. You can use the following also:

```
UPDATE your_table_name 
SET newtime = `date` + INTERVAL '2:30:10' HOUR_SECOND;
```

Comment: will this over write the current 'date' column? I need that also to be stored.

Comment: @CCC no, it is updating into a new column `newtime`. You will have to first create that `newtime` column. and then run this update query

Comment: @CCC check the updated answer please. I have changed the function to be used.

Comment: I created a new column newtime and gave the command. It is printing NULL in the fields. update userevents set newtime= convert_tz(`date`,'+00:00:00','+02:30:10');

Comment: @CCC please check the updated answer. I have used a different function now. it is using `date_add`

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly now. Why was convert_tz printing NULL? Just now noticed question has a downvote, what is wrong?

Comment: @CCC I rechecked documentation, `convert_tz` works only with standard timezone values. if it was just 2 hours 30 mins, it may have worked; 2 hours 30 minutes 10 seconds is not a standard timezone difference value. Check details at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: @CCC dont worry abt the downvote. I upvoted back to nullify it. SO community has all kinds of people

Comment: MySQL doesn't require an explicit call to `DATE_ADD` function...  `... SET newtime = date + INTERVAL '2:30:10' HOUR_SECOND`